# Importing Data from other Workbook Based on User Input

Tags: excel, vba, input, import

I'd like my excel file to import worksheets from other workbooks. The user puts in a path where the files to be imported are stored, some divisions of a company (up to 3 divisions per import), pushes the macro button, excel should then look for the files of the divisions (f.ex. HR.csv) and import certain columns into a new sheet. Input looks like this:

[image: input looks like this]

I have no problem with the importing business but i don't get how i can tell excel where to get the files from and which workbooks to open given that excel has to open more than 1 workbook -.-

Comment: Set a path variable to the folder containing the files and use the Dir function to loop over files with? Or have an array of file names which you loop over concatenating each filename with the path variable and passing to workbooks.open e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243201/vba-excel-looping-through-folder   You could assign the path directly to a variable in the code, assign to the result of an inputbox (user would add in path at prompt) or pick up from a cell within the spreadsheet and assign to a variable in the code.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly with the path variable approach!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started:

```
Sub Importsheet() 
    Dim Importsheet As Worksheet 'Imports worksheet from a closed workbook
    Sheets.Add Type:= "C:\Doc\Excel\HR.csv" 
End Sub
```